# How to get React .js file to format correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have a file named `App.js` in Visual Studio Code and the file actually renders fine in the browser, but it does not format correctly:

[image]

I have switched the file type to `javascriptreact`:

[image]

But it still won't format with `SHIFT-ALT-F`.

Here is my `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
}
```

What else do I need to set so that `SHIFT-ALT-F` properly formats my React Javascript file?

Comment: You could add Prettier extension to the Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Remove the current `defaultFormatter` setting from `settings.json`

Comment: @Agney I removed all four `defaultFormatter` settings but it still won't format.

Comment: As what @copperi said try it with Prettier plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode